# Prisma.io Is there a way to AND two ORs in prisma.findMany

Tags: javascript, orm, prisma, prisma2

I am trying to do some more complex query like this using prisma.io:

```
prisma.someModel.findMany({
    where: {
      AND: [
        {
          OR: [
            { firstName: { contains: 'John' } },
            { lastName: { contains: 'John' } }
          ]
        },
        {
          OR: [
            { firstName: { contains: 'Doe' } },
            { lastName: { contains: 'Doe' } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
})
```

Is there a way to do something like this?

Comment: What exactly you want to find? What result you expect, "John John" or "Doe Doe" or what?

Comment: { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe'}
or
{ firstName: 'Doe', lastName: 'John' }
both